# swift - using .map on struct array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

i have a struct array that i want "break up" into smaller arrays that can be called as needed or at least figure out how i can map the items needed off one text value.

the struct:

```
struct CollectionStruct {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var title : String
    var image : PFFile
    var id: String
}
```

and the array made from the struct

```
var collectionArray = [CollectionStruct]()

var i = 0
for item in collectionArray {
    print(collectionArray[i].name)    
    i += 1  
}
```

printing partArray[i].name gives the following result:

```
pk00_pt01
pk00_pt02
pk00_pt03
pk01_pt01
pk01_pt02
pk01_pt03
pk01_pt04
pk01_pt05
pk01_pt06
pk01_pt07
pk01_pt08
```

this is just some test values but there could be thousands of entries here so i wanted to filter the entire array just by the first 4 characters of [i].name  i can achieve this by looping through as above but is this achievable using something like .map?

Comment: `var partArray = collectionArray.map{$0.name}`  then ... `print(partArray)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*i wanted to filter the entire array just by the first 4 characters of [i].name*"? You want to get an array of strings of the first 4 characters of each `name` of each element?

Comment: Also your for loop can be expressed as just `for item in collectionArray { print(item.name) }`

Comment: Are you showing us all the code above? It seems like some is missing such as where you are filtering based on the first 4 characters? You may be looking for Swift's `filter` function but your question is unclear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wanted to filter the entire array just by the first 4 characters of
>   [i].name

You can achieve this by *filtering* the array based on the `substring` value of the `name`, as follows:

```
let filteredArray = collectionArray.filter {
    $0.name.substring(to: $0.name.index($0.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)).lowercased() == "pk00"
    // or instead of "pk00", add the first 4 characters you want to compare
}
```

`filteredArray` will be filled based on what is the compared string.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Glad to help, btw there is even a shorter solution (as @Hamish suggested), by using [hasPrefix(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix), but that won't be 100% accurate for comparing only the first four characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group all data automatically by their name prefix. You could use a reducer to generate a dictionary of grouped items. Something like this:

```
let groupedData = array.reduce([String: [String]]()) { (dictionary, myStruct) in
    let grouper = myStruct.name.substring(to: myStruct.name.index(myStruct.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
    var newDictionart = dictionary
    if let collectionStructs = newDictionart[grouper] {
        newDictionart[grouper] = collectionStructs + [myStruct.name]
    } else {
        newDictionart[grouper] = [myStruct.name]
    }
    return newDictionart
}
```

This will produce a dictionary like this:

```
[
    "pk00": ["pk00_pt01", "pk00_pt02", "pk00_pt03"],
    "pk01": ["pk01_pt01", "pk01_pt02", "pk01_pt03", "pk01_pt04", "pk01_pt05", "pk01_pt06", "pk01_pt07"],
    "pk02": ["pk02_pt08"]
]
```

Comment: I struggle understanding the shorthand syntax like $0 ect. So this is a nice way of getting the result.

Comment: Yeah, in this case shorthand syntax could be hard to read. And additionally the complexity to generate this dictionary is linear O(n) but to read the sliced arrays will be a constant O(1) complexity. With filter you always will had an O(n) complexity with default search.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am understanding you correctly but it sounds like you are looking for this...

To create a new array named `partArray` from an already existing array named `collectionArray` (that is of type CollectionStruct) you would do...

`var partArray = collectionArray.map{$0.name}`